# PHP Net_SSH2 cannot conect

Tags: php, net-ssh, ssh2-exec

I am trying to use Net_SSH2 class for login in ssh server and i get error:

> **Notice**:  No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in **/var/www/html/includes/classes/Net/SSH2.php** on line **1389**

Code in line 1389 was:

```
$decrypt = $this->_array_intersect_first($encryption_algorithms, $this->encryption_algorithms_server_to_client);
        $decryptKeyLength = $this->_encryption_algorithm_to_key_size($decrypt);
        if ($decryptKeyLength === null) {
            user_error('No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found');
            return $this->_disconnect(NET_SSH2_DISCONNECT_KEY_EXCHANGE_FAILED);
        }
```

My PHP file for process:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.168.111.159');
if (!$ssh->login('root', 'xxxxxxx')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

PS. -> i also get Login Failed, but my login was OK i try true terminal on web server its works fine.

Question is why the login fail bat my data was correct and how fix error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add on top of SSH2.PHP

```
set_include_path('includes/classes/Net/');
```

And login works fine plus error was gone!

Answer (score 0):

some one can add for php7 , ultimately it is  resolved on  Ubuntu 16.04.

by adding two lines in my code

```php
set_include_path('/usr/share/php/phpseclib/');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
```